# how to add child element to parent in wpf using linq to xml concept?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
    XElement school = new XElement("school",
                                            new XElement("SectionA",
                                              new XElement("Student", "guna"),
                                              new XElement("Student", "Anbu"),
                                              new XElement("Student", "Chandru")));

 XElement Student = new XElement("Student","Rajesh"); 
 school.Save(@AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Joiningelements.xml");
```

Here i want add **student** element child of **SectionA** in **school** element.

Comment: What has this got to do with WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this

```
XElement Student = new XElement("Student", "Rajesh");

school.Element("SectionA").Add(Student);
```